# Making a library importable using webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, electron, babeljs

I am trying to publish a package on `npm` ([this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rom-scraper)) that I am developing using `webpack` and `babel`. My code is written in `ES6`. I have a file in my sources, `index.js`, that (for the moment) exports one of my library's core components, it simply goes like this:

```
import TheGamesDb from './scrapers/thegamesdb';
export { TheGamesDb };
```

I am using `webpack` and `babel` to create a dist `index.js` that is my package's main file. My `webpack.config.js` goes like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
    development: ['babel-polyfill', './src/development.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: '.',
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'rom-scraper',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

Now when I load my package in another project and try to `import` my export `TheGamesDb` simply like this

```
import { TheGamesDb } from 'rom-scraper';
```

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

It is to be noted that I am importing my library in `electron`.

*Update: Electron seems to be the main problem here and it is not even my library but a dependency that throws this error (only in Electron)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't any of the things in my question but `node-expat` not working in `electron`. I switched to an alternative library and it's all right now.